# Know any games designed for old game systems like Orion or Sly

Tags: game-design, history, game-system

A [Game System](https://boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/game_system&noredirect=1) is a set of components and/or rules that are intended to be used to create games.  That is, one set of components that allows to play several diffrent games.

Recent game systems like [piecepack](http://www.ludism.org/ppwiki/), [Decktet](http://decktet.wikidot.com/), or [Stonehenge](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/20436/stonehenge) have tons of games to try, but older game systems like [Sly](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/5096/sly) and [Orion](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/8923/orion) only seem to have the [official](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/6107/slyrules-pdf) [rules (PDF)](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/Orion.PDF) that came with them.

Somehow [Icehouse](http://www.looneylabs.com/whybuy/LooneyPyramids.html) managed to survive from the 1980's until the web could attract a community for it, does anybody know of any additional rule sets written for other game systems published before 1995?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody else seems to have made any new games for Sly, I [did it myself](http://donkirkby.blogspot.com/2011/08/sly-corporation.html). Well, I guess some credit should go to Eric Solomon.

Answer (score 0):

Seven years after I asked, Chris Goodwin designed [Tingle](http://www.ludism.org/ppwiki/Tingle) to be playable on Sly, piecepack, and Looney Pyramids.